# Picocli - "Missing required Parameters" even when passed parameters

Tags: java, command-line-interface, picocli

```
@Parameters(paramLabel = "AMOUNT", description = "the depth to scrape for")
private int amount;

@Parameters(paramLabel = "ENTRY_POINT", description = "the entry point for the scrape")
private String entryPoint;
```

I have these Parameters in my Main class.
When I run the program with `ClassName 5 https://www.baeldung.com/` I get

```json
Missing required parameters: 'AMOUNT', 'ENTRY_POINT'
Usage: <main class> AMOUNT ENTRY_POINT
      AMOUNT        the depth to scrape for
      ENTRY_POINT   the entry point for the scrape
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: This is where a [mcve] is useful. No-one could have answered your question without basically *guessing* what you'd done... whereas if you'd written out a minimal example, you may well have found the problem before even asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved; I didn't pass the arguments from the command-line in my main-mathod ...

Pretty stupid lol.

Before, not working

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var cmd = new CommandLine(new Scraper());
    cmd.execute();
}
```

After, working

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var cmd = new CommandLine(new Scraper());
    cmd.execute(args);
}
```